# How to sort from highest to lowest occurence from within a multivalued attribute using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, database-schema

I am using MySQL and have 2 tables for a restaurant menu called:

1. `Item (Item_Code, Item_Name, Price, Item_Type, Location, Notes)`
2. `Order (Order_Code, Item_Code, Ingredient_Code)`

The attribute `'Item_Code'` in the `'Order'` table is multivalued.

How can I write an SQL query to show the `item_code` and `item_name` (from the 'Item' table), in order of occurrences(from highest to lowest in the `'Order'` table?

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Sample data:

**Item Table**:

```
(Item_Code, Item_Name, Price, Item_Type, Location, Notes)
'I001'  'Chicken Rice'  '7.00'  'Main Course'   'Kitchen'   'Non-vegetarian'  
'I002'  'French Fries'  '3.00'  'Appetiser' 'Kitchen'   'Vegetarian'  
'I003'  'Iced Lemon Tea'    '2.00'  'Beverage'  'Bar'   'Non-Alcoholic'  
'I004'  'Fish and Chips'    '8.00'  'Main Course'   'Kitchen'   'Halal'  
'I005'  'Vanilla Ice Cream' '4.00'  'Dessert'   'Kitchen'   'NA'
```

**Order Table**:

```
Order_Code, Item_Code, Ingredient_Code
'O222221', 'I001 I002', 'NA'  
'O222222', 'I001 I003', 'AI03'  
'O222223', 'I004 I005 I001', 'AI01'  
'O222224', 'I002 I002 I004', 'AI04'  
'O222225', 'I001 I002 I003', 'AI05'
```

Comment: Please show example data and expected output

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-valued"?  Please provide some sample data and what you want for results.

Comment: by multi-valued, i mean that the 'Item_Code' in the Order table can have many values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very poor data layout.  You should have a third table, `OrderItems` that has one row per order and item in the order.

You can do what you want using string manipulations.  Unfortunately, you cannot take advantage of indexes and other database optimizations.

```
select i.item_code, count(*) as cnt
from orders o join
     items i
     on concat(' ', o.item_code, ' ') like concat('% ', i.item_code, ' %')
group by i.item_code
order by count(*) desc;
```

EDIT:

You can create the `OrderItems` table by running a query quite similar to the one above:

```
select o.order_id, i.item_code
from orders o join
     items i
     on concat(' ', o.item_code, ' ') like concat('% ', i.item_code, ' %');
```

Then insert this into the new table or use `create table as`.

Comment: thanks Gordon. Is there a way to create the third table for OrderItems using SQL?

Comment: thank you very much Gordon! Now it is much more logical.